# The Distribution of the Linear Interpolation of Normally Sampled Points

Tags: probability-distributions

This is mostly me [reasking this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908949/what-is-the-probability-distribution-after-interpolation) because I believe I have an alternative approach to a similar idea, whereas this seems to be adding some kind of discretization instead.

Let $(X_i)_{i=0,\cdots,n}$ be i.i.d normal standard normal variables. We define the linear interpolation $L_n((X_i)_{i=0,\cdots,n},Y)$ to be:

$$
L_n((X_i)_{i=0,\cdots,n},Y) = 
\begin{cases} 
X_1 + (X_2 - X_1)Y & 0 \leq Y \leq 1\\
X_2 + (X_3 - X_2)(Y - 1) & 1 < Y \leq 2 \\
\vdots \\
X_{n-1} + (X_n - X_{n-1})(Y - n - 1) & n-1 < Y \leq n
\end{cases}
$$

Giving us the intuitive plot for a given sample of $(X_i)_{i=0,\cdots,n}$:

[image]

Reasking the original question with this new approach:

1. Assuming that $Y\sim \mathcal{U}(0,n)$ what is the distribution of $L_n((X_i)_{i=0,\cdots,n},Y)$?
2. In the limit at $n\to\infty$ what is the limit distribution $L_\infty((X_i)_{i=0,\cdots,n},Y)$?

Comment: If you write $L_n(y)$ like that, it means that $x_1, ...,x_n$ are not variables of $L$ and are known (in other words, not random). I suggest to write $L(Y, (X_i) _{i=1,...,n})$ to indicate $L$ is a function of $Y$ and $X_i$ for $i=1,..,n$. $Y$ and $X$ are written in capital letter to indicate that they are random variables.

Comment: That's a fair comment, edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing on a single segment we have the product between a normal and uniform distribution given by:

$$X_i+(X_{i+1}-X_i)Y$$

So we're looking at the product between $A\sim\mathcal{N}(0,2)$ and $B\sim U(0,1)$ plus $C\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ - this isn't a "named" distribution - we'll start by focusing on $AB$ which we know is [product of a uniform and a normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008559/pdf-of-product-of-standard-normal-and-uniform?noredirect=1&lq=1) - so is given by the PDF:

$$
PDF_{AB}(z) =  \frac{\Gamma(0, \frac{z^2}{4})}{4 \sqrt{\pi}}
$$

Where Gamma in this context is the upper incomplete gamma function, it looks like this:

[image]

This is not a normal distribution, and computing, $AB+C$ requires a convolution that I'm not sure how to do:
$$
\text{PDF}_{AB+C}(z) = \frac{\Gamma(0, \frac{z^2}{4})}{4 \sqrt{\pi}}
* \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-z^2}{2}
$$

However, using Monte Carlo simulations, we get the following distribution which isn't normal:

[image]

It fails the Shapiro-Wilks, Anderson-Darling and Kolmogorov-Smirnov normality tests and has an excess kurtosis of $0.369$, so it is very slightly leptokurtic or fat-tailed.

Extending this to arbitrary/intervals, we must always select from one of these intervals that we've already defined, so we will always sample from this distribution, even in the limit.